# ProtoBuff + python

Tags: python, google-protobuf

Суть проблемы:

При компиляции кода на python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import socket
import message_pb2
import sys

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('localhost', 8080))

Request = message_pb2.request()
Request.a=1
Request.b=2
Request.c=3
for i in [1,2,3]:
a = int (input())
sock.send(Request)
```

Выдает ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\protobuf\client.py", line 5, in <module>
    import message_pb2
  File "D:\protobuf\message_pb2.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
ImportError: No module named google.protobuf
```

В чем может быть проблема? Файл protobuff со структурой успешно откомпилирован и лежит в папке с файлом ( где код `client.py` )

Заранее спасибо

Comment: У Вас установлен пакет [`protobuf`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/protobuf/2.6.1)?

Comment: Протокол скачен с (https://github.com/google/protobuf) полностью все и лежит в той же папке.

Comment: Если нужно по-другому установить, напишите пожалуйста.

Comment: Я, на самом деле, уже час назад написал, но подумал, что неправильно понял Вашу проблему и удалил ответ, оставив уточняющий комментарий.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR;** - воспользуйтесь пакетным менеджером для установки пакета [protobuf](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/protobuf/2.6.1) (начиная с Python 3.4 и Python 2.7.9, `pip` идет в комплекте):

```
python -m pip install protobuf
```

#### Почему не работает метод, который Вы использовали?

Рассмотрим следующую файловую структуру:

```
$ tree
.
├── client.py
├── google
│   └── __init__.py
├── message_pb2.py
└── protobuf.py

$ cat client.py
import message_pb2

$ cat message_pb2.py
from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor

$ cat protobuf.py
def descriptor():
    pass
```

При попытке запустить файл `client.py`, Python выдаст ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 1, in <module>
    import message_pb2
  File "/home/soon/Src/Python/test_20412/message_pb2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
ImportError: No module named 'google.protobuf'
```

И это логично, поскольку директория `google` содержит в себе только файл `__init__.py`. Если мы переместим файл `protobuf.py` в директорию `google`:

```
$ tree
.
├── client.py
├── google
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── protobuf.py
└── message_pb2.py
```

то все выполнится без ошибок.

#### Почему стоит использовать пакетный менеджер, а не закидывать файлы руками?

По той же самой причине, по которой Вы устанавливаете программы через мастера установки программ, а не копируете ручками все файлы по папкам.

Comment: в cmd захожу в папку, где у меня client.py, message_pb2.py и где папка google, пишу в cmd  "python -m pip install protobuf "

и ошибки (пример одной из них):

Traceback (most recent call last) :
   File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 223, in main status = self/run(options,args)

и того же рода ошибки (кол-во 20-30 штук)

Comment: Обновите свой вопрос, добавив в него Traceback. Без него сложно понять, что у Вас происходит

Comment: Не получается показать дерево каталогов. Я думаю проблема в файлах, которые нужно подругизть дополнительно с protobuf Для python

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\protobuf\python\client.py", line 5, in <module>
    import message_pb2
  File "D:\protobuf\python\message_pb2.py", line 10, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor_pb2
ImportError: cannot import name descriptor_pb2

вот ошибка новая

Comment: Нужна версия Python и выхлоп команды `python -m pip freeze`.

Comment: Python 2.7.10

При выполнении в cmd " python -m pip freeze " 
Ошибок нет, но и результата нет

Comment: Хорошо, а тогда вывод у `python -m pip install protobuf` какой?

Comment: http://cs623427.vk.me/v623427999/34667/VqhKZeHj0Co.jpg

Не знаю как по другому выложить. Сделал скрин

Comment: Разобрался. Была проблема в версии protobuff для python, Скачал 2.6.1 ( такую же как и protoc ) и заработало.

Answer (score 1):

Была проблема с версиями protobuf. Они должны быть идентичные.